# Pointer to a literal?

Tags: c++, pointers, literals

While reading *C++ Primer*, I came across this line:
`const char *cp = "Hello World";`

To my understanding, `"Hello World"` is a string literal, which is an array of constant characters. Since an array decays to a pointer to the first element in an array. Does that mean `cp` points to `H` which is a literal? Isn't it impossible to have a pointer to a literal, since a pointer has to point to the address of an object in memory?

Comment: Why do you think `"Hello World"` is not in memory?  Was trying to find this ... _"...String literals have static storage duration, and thus exist in memory for the life of the program...."_ source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal

Comment: According to [stackexchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/224501/why-are-pointers-to-literals-not-possible), a literal does not occupy any memory. @RichardCritten

Comment: Simple answer different sort of literal: integer vs string.  Trying to create an answer will include this info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The storage type of the literals types: boolean, integer, floating, character and nullptr is not specified and therefore they do not need to have a storage location in memory.

The storage type of literal string type is specified:
*"...String literals have static storage duration, and thus exist in memory for the life of the program..."* source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal

Therefore the address of a literal string can be taken and stored in a `const char *`.

As suggested by @MichaelKenzel :

From the C++17 draft standard (n4659) https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/lex.string#16

> Evaluating a string-literal results in a string literal object with
>   static storage duration, initialized from the given characters as
>   specified above. Whether all string literals are distinct (that is,
>   are stored in nonoverlapping objects) and whether successive
>   evaluations of a string-literal yield the same or a different object
>   is unspecified. [ Note: The effect of attempting to modify a string
>   literal is undefined.  — end note ]

Comment: I suggest to add a link to the corresponding paragraph of the C++17 draft: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/lex.string#16